# Brightness Get Maximum at Every Restart

Tags: brightness

Brightness is not remembering it's last state. It make full brightness at every restart. 
I don't want that, I want my brightness(specific) -echo 50/6.

Just it should remember my last brightness setting by any way.

Note;echo X not working.

My machine is LENOVO G400 Ideapad

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer :

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/fix-brightness-getting-reset-to-very.html

Check it..